# GroupMember Creation via REST API

Tags: api, rest

I am trying to create a new GroupMember via the REST API.  My payload looks like:

> { 
>       "GroupId": "00Gj00000016xpyEAA",
>       "UserOrGroupId": "005j000000C8xj6AAB" 
>   }

and the response I get:

> [
>   {
>   "message": "field integrity exception: unknown (invalid user or group: 005j000000C8xj6)",
>   "errorCode": "FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION",
>   "fields": [
>   "unknown"
>   ]
>   }
>   ]

It looks like the last 3 chars of the UserOrGroupId are being truncated.  Anyone know if this is a known problem, or am I just not doing it right?

Comment: The last 3 chars are only used if the id is case insensitive. They are not needed. Is the group you are adding to a Customer Community Group?

Comment: I think CaspNZ is right. You should use 15 digit case sensitive id. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-do-unique-IDs-work-in-Salesforce-1327108651310&

Comment: When I use the api to request all users, the AAB is part of the ID on that one, that I get back from SalesForce.  The group is a new Public Group that I created previously and is now 'known'.  Since it is SalesForce saying that it cannot find  the 15-char user id, asking it to do so does not seem like the way to go but I did try that - same result.

Answer (score 0):

The api I POSTed to is:  https://myinstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/GroupMember.
I was finally able to get it to work with no changes to payload, after I changed the user's profile to something other than 'Chatter Free User'.